# In Sklearn, how can I pass an arbitrary number of models to a class?

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, scikit-learn

If I write something like

```
class test_class(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, model = LogisticRegression()):
        self.model = model
    # ... #
```

Then I can do this

```
test = test_class()
test.get_params()
```

And I get the parameters of LogisticRegression() as part of the parameters of my class, in the format "model__". This would let me use the class with something like GridSearchCV and easily access the arguments of LogisticRegression.

Is there any way of doing this for an arbitrary number of models?

I have tried a few things, including using a **kwargs argument like this:

```
class test_class(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, model = LogisticRegression(), **kwargs):
        self.model = model

        for key in kwargs:
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
    # ... #
```

And then if I do

```
test = test_class(model_2 = RandomForestClassifier())
test.get_params()
```

I just get the same as before (although model_2 is added as an attribute).

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward but I'm not getting anywhere - maybe what I am trying to do doesn't even make sense. The goal of my class would be some sort of model ensembler that I can use with GridSearchCV.

Does anyone have any ideas?

edit:

An example of the parameter grid I would like to give to GridSearchCV is, considering the second example:

```
{
    model__C : [1, 10],
    model_2__n_estimators : [10, 100]
}
```

The first line works as expected (considering how Pipelines work with GridSearchCV), but the second does not (as the parameters are not found in get_params()).

My fit, predict and score methods are all working fine, it is just an issue of passing the arguments to the additional models I want to pass to my class.

Comment: Please explain with an example of what you exaclty want to do in GridSearch? How would you provide the params to the models here? Are you looking for something like a FeatureUnion or Pipeline?

Comment: @VivekKumar

If my second example had worked, I would have liked to give GridSearchCV a parameter grid something like (copying what you would do with a pipeline):

model__C : [1, 10], # parameter for logistic regression
model_2__n_estimators : [10, 100] # parameter for random forest

The first line works fine, the second does not, as the parameters are not included when I do _test.get_params()_.

Comment: Yes, because get_params() will only get the attributes set at the constructor in `init()`. Not others. Because other attributes can contain values depending on the data. Maybe you can pass a list or dict of models at the init()

Comment: So any kwargs arguments will never be included in get_params()?

Comment: As you [see here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L200), its specifically excluding params, which are specified as `**kwargs`